# Can PDF.js be used after pdf has already been downloaded?

Tags: javascript, pdf, vue.js, pdf.js

I would like to use PDF.js (or Viewer.js) with a Flask app where I have already downloaded the file from a server.

Rather than using

```
PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf')
```

I want to view the pdf that was downloaded to the browser via an Ajax call. (This allows more server control over providing to the client only files that the user is allowed access to)

eg in Flask

```
@mayapp.route('/files/<int:file_id>', methods=['GET'])
def file_access(file_id: int=None):
    // lookup access and file path in database, get file
    return send_file(file_path)
```

On the client side:

```
fetchData: function () {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: '/myapp/files/' + this.file_id,
      dataType: ...,
      headers: ...,
      data: {}
    })
    .then((response) => {
        this.file = response.data
      })
}
```

Then I would like to feed this.file into PDF.js to view it.

eg using a base64 encoded string as per [Flask / postgres - display pdf with PDFJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265079/flask-postgres-display-pdf-with-pdfjs):

```
var doc = PDFJS.getDocument({data: pdfData})
```

But I cant work out how to exactly render the document. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the PDF's pages and paint each page to a canvas.

Start by creating an HTML element into which the canvases can be inserted:

```
<body>
    <div id="pdf-view"></div>
</body>
```

And then use PDF.js's `.numPages` and `.getPage()` tools, as show below, to create and paint to canvases:

```
async function renderPDFPage(pdf, pgNum) {
    const pg = await pdf.getPage(pgNum)
    const scale = 2
    const viewport = pg.getViewport(scale)
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    const canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d')
    canvas.height = viewport.height
    canvas.width = viewport.width
    document.getElementById('pdf-view').appendChild(canvas)
    await pg.render({canvasContext, viewport})
}

async function renderPDF(pdf) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= pdf.numPages; i++) {
        await renderPDFPage(pdf, i)
    }
}

const pdf = PDFJS.getDocument({data: pdfData})
renderPDF(pdf)
```